# Java || while statement with Infinite Loop

Tags: java

Why does the following produce an infinite loop?

```
    int sum = 0;    
    int k = 1;
    while (sum < 12 || k < 4)
    sum += k;

    System.out.println(sum);
```

I would assume the output would be 12, once sum reaches 12 while k remains at 1.

Comment: indentation problem....

Comment: `k` is still less than 4, so the condition remains true.

Comment: increment k value

Comment: multiple choice question

Answer (score 1):

you should use while (sum < 12 && k < 4), otherwise K < 4 will always be true and the loop will continue running.

if you use OR, the loops continue when one of those conditions are true. The conditions are for the loop to continue, not to stop.

```
false || true == true
true || true == true
false || false == false

false && true == false
true && true == true
false && false == false
```

the resulting true or false determines if the loop continues

Comment: But, because it is an OR statment, wouldn't it check to see if sum < 12 OR k < 4?

Comment: It was a multiple choice question

Comment: @Kyle McAllister, if you use OR, the loops continue when one of those conditions are true. The conditions are for the loop to continue, not to stop.
false || true == true

Comment: @Kyle McAllister I updated the answer to clarify it better

Answer (score 1):

k isn't incremented.

```
int sum = 0; 
int k = 1; 

while (sum < 12 || k < 4) {
    sum += k; 
     k++;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Why would this be necessary, wouldn't the loop break once either sum < 12 OR k < 4?  Plus this would yield a different sum?

Comment: @KyleMcAllister the loop CONTINUES if some of the conditions are satisfied

Answer (score 1):

In your code `k`  doesn't increment, so the condition remains true. So that's why your loop is infinite.

```
 int sum = 0;    // sum is 0
  int k = 1;       // k is 1 
   while (sum < 12 || k < 4) {
    sum += k;   // sum is incremented by 1 each time it loops
  }
```

System.out.println(sum);

But here your value of k is still less than 4. So it loops infinite.

EDIT: Well i'm making it a bit more clear

Here is your `while` loop

`while (sum < 12 || k < 4)`

It means either `sum < 12` has to be true or  `k < 4` has to be true, to loop the  `while` loop.

And here your `k < 4` condition is still true. so that's why it keep looping infinite.

Comment: Right, it was a multiple choice question (not my code).  Once the sum gets to 12, would that not suffice the or statement and end it?

Comment: No,  Both of them should be true to terminate the loop.

Comment: Got it, thank you.  I was thinking completely wrong.  I was thinking it would break when 1 OR the other were satisfied.  It is actually while one or the other is true it continues, not breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `k` value remains constant across all the iterations.

Your loop condition is `sum<12` or `k<4`. Since you are not changing the k value across iterations it will be always less than 4 and the loop keeps on going.

Answer (score 0):

You use the || statement. Read any documentation about "|| &&" || => OR.
If left side of statement is true and right is false = true (Using ||)